# what happens when an Erinyes uses different ropes to entangle?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, animated-objects

The [Erinyes](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/devil.htm#erinyes) devil has the extraordinary ability to Entangle an opponent, it reads:

> Each erinyes carries a stout rope some 50 feet long that [entangles](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#entangled) opponents of any size as an [animate rope](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/animateRope.htm) spell (caster level 16th). An erinyes can hurl its rope 30 feet with no range penalty.

However, the entry is not specific about the type and properties of the rope (`stout` and `some 50 feet long` are hardly very specific) and I could totally imagine a devil with a fondness for tying up its victims to not use a standard piece of rope. Probably it would use a 2 inch diameter rope of 50 feet or a 3 inch diameter rope of 32 feet, or maybe even a piece of rare [bloodvine rope](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/hunting-camping-survival-geaR/#TOC-Bloodvine-Rope). Now, such ropes could be animated by a 16th level caster like the Erinyes, but the Animate Rope spell assumes a standard 1 inch diameter piece of hempen rope is used.. How would hit points, break DC, escape artist DC and spellcasting Concentration DC change for ropes of different diameter or for bloodvine rope when used for Animate Rope?

Comment: Is there a citation for different diameter ropes or are you applying real world knowledge to their existance?  All the ropes I see on the (very good) bloodvine link have info, so I may be missing the Q.

Comment: the properties of rope as specified in the Animate Rope spell are for a 1 inch diameter rope only, I cannot find any properties for 2 inch or 3 inch diameter ropes, would the spell be any different for those ropes? (I would expect so.) or for other types of rope like the bloodvine?

Comment: Can you elaborate, why do you think erinyes even may try to use another type of rope? To me, it may be (and probably is) a property of a rope, not of the devil herself, to entangle people. Or do you may be wont answers about Rope Trick universally?

Comment: @annoyingimp you're correct the rope and its properties (together with Animate Rope) are at the center of this question, the Erinyes is the one using the ropes and for its fondness of ropes it's only logical to say it would try and use the best possible rope to entangle its victims (within the boundaries of Animate Rope cast at caster level 16th). However, it's not clear what the properties of different types of ropes are and how Animate Rope would affect them.

Comment: It depends on where devils get those ropes from, doesn't it? Are another kinds awailable to them? Or do you think, any rope erinyes takes becomes animated?

Comment: @annoyingimp _"To me, it may be (and probably is) a property of a rope, not of the devil herself, to entangle people.“_ - Extraordinary abilities always refer to creatures, not items. Thus the ability _Entangle_ is an ability of the _Erinyes_ and not of the ropes they use. Since their ability works like the _animate rope_ spell it‘s reasonable to allow any rope within spell limits.

Comment: @PeregrinTook I agree, it should work the way you describe. But, take a look at the [drow elf](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/elf.htm#drow) entry.

Comment: @annoyingimp … um, I see. In this case "extraordinary" refers to the poisonous effect - but anybody could use a drow's poisoned weapon. You have a point there, I admit.

Comment: @PeregrinTook It also worth noting that you usually shouldn't be able to make something magical with an (Ex) ability. It probably should be (Su) for how does it worded. Maybe (Sp), if there may be contineous (Sp) abilities that do not require activation.

Comment: @annoyingimp The _entangle_ ability works _"as an animate rope spell"_ but this doesn't mean it is magical. As I understand it, it's a special attack/fighting technique that just uses the mechanics of the spell.

Comment: @PeregrinTook Actually, after (by some strange habit it always happens after, sadly) writing my previous comment, I thought about it myself. It is probably the case, and your answer is totally valid. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A standard rope has 2 HP/inch of thickness (PH, 166). So if you increase the diameter of the rope the number of HP will change accordingly.

The DC for an escape artist check to escape from an *animated rope* spell is 20 (PH, 73). It doesn't change if the rope is thinner or thicker.

The DC for the concentration check also remains the same. A creature tied up by the spell becomes [*entangled*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/conditionSummary.htm#entangled). Being entangled is a defined condition which says *"An entangled character who attempts to cast a spell must make a Concentration check (DC 15 + the spell’s level) or lose the spell."*

The general DC for bursting rope bonds is 23 (PH, 166). The rules don't differentiate between ropes of various diameter so it's up to the DM to adjust the DC. A standard rope is 1-inch-diameter, so maybe add a +2 for every additional inch.

If you use a special rope like the *Bloodvine Rope* (Pathfinder, not DnD 3.5!), HP, hardness and break DC would be those of that specific rope.
Since there are set DCs for the concentration check while being *entangled* and the escape artist check to escape from an *animated rope* spell, these DCs stay the same no matter what kind of rope is being used.